# How can I click div button in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, button, web, driver

Does anyone know how I can click (in Java) the button with following HTML code?

```
<div role="button" id=":t5.ss" class="c-N-K a-b a-b-va KMD69e-bU2Jkc-b DF" tabindex="0" aria-label="Join as John" style="user-select: none;">Join</div>
```

My snippet code in Java:

```
driver.get("https://www.somepage.com");
... enter new tab ...
Thread.sleep(10000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='button']")).click();
```

And I've got

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
no such element: Unable to locate element
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@role='button']"}
```

I've tried also following without success:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':t5.ss']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Join as John']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id=':t5.ss']")).click();
```

Comment: Your problem is not clicking, it is finding it.

Comment: What have you tried? The `aria-label`, `role`, or even by `text()` using an `xpath`, or some combination would probably work fine. I can give a clearer answer, but I'm not really sure what you've tried at this point.

Comment: Have you waited for the thing to be displayed/visible?

Comment: yes I've been waiting 10 seconds

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=':t5.ss']")).click(); there is no waiting in any of these lines

Comment: these are only my examples which I tried, and nothing works

Comment: I suggest you post your code as it is written

Comment: If none of this stuff works, you might be clicking on the wrong element. Meaning, maybe this `div` you have in your question isn't actually the thing you want to click even though at first glance you think it is. although your `NoSuchElementException` doesn't make any sense if it's there on the page after your 10 second sleep

Comment: Is this element located within an iFrame?

Comment: you are right probably, this element is in the new tab, I should switch there

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has methods named By.id() and By.className() to find the button and use click() to click the selected button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("element id")).click()
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.className("element class")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click an element, it has to be visible and displayed.

WebElement e = find(...); //POM search

```
if (e != null){
                Thread.sleep(...);
                while (!e.isDisplayed())
                        Thread.sleep(...);
                e.click();
}
```

This has worked for me a lot.

Comment: this element is visible, I am sure

Comment: There are better ways to wait for an element to be visible. For example:
`new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by))`

Comment: Just an extra layer of indirection that decreases throughput. But if you prefer it that way.

Comment: @efekctive what happens in your code when `e == null` because it wasn't yet loaded in the DOM? Your `Thread.sleeps` wouldn't get triggered, right? There are many reasons `WebDriverWait` is the preferred method. Proper timeouts, no Thread blocking, more versatile conditions to wait for.

You can read more about it in the link I provided in my answer.

You can also use the `WebDriverWait` to instantiate a `WebElement`, for example:
`WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));` Returning the element only if it's clickable.

Comment: if you happen to read the code if (e !=null) means that it will never be null. That I already caught the exception. Before you think you have an answer read and understand. So please understand the code posted. Second understand the tool you use. I am not going to bother with down votes. It is a waste of time

Comment: Second, "Proper timeouts, no Thread blocking" shows an utter lack of understanding general programming paradigms. Third You need to read about POM and tell the OP to use. Because you would need to explain how POM would return an element not in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Thread.sleep` in your tests is bad practice because you will never know if the page and the elements you want to use actually are finished loading.

It's better to use explicit waits. Here's an example:

`new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));`

More information about that can be [found here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

The `NoSuchElementException` points towards three possibilities:
a) there simply is no such element that you are trying to find in the HTML
b) the element isn't loaded yet, if so use `WebDriverWait`
c) the element is part of an iframe and cannot be found unless you switch to that iframe

If c) is correct you can switch to the iframe with:
`driver.switchTo().frame(d().findElement(iframe));`

Comment: yes robert I suppose c) option is the reason. I've added following code:

ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role='button']")).click();

--- But after that have this exception: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: So it's not in an iFrame, but in another tab. I haven't thought about that when writing my answer, but I'm glad I gave you the right idea.

Comment: So how does the driverwait wait without an sleep, just spinning loops? If checking for e.isDisplayed() returns true is the element loaded or not? So much nonsense

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click(), try sendKeys().

Example:

```
myDiv.sendKeys(Keys.Enter); // or Keys.Return
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use id as it is unique to identify the element 
driver.findElement(By.id(":t5.ss")).click();

Also check if the element is displayed and enabled by using isDisplayed() and isEnabled() to click.